# Android Browser relative height inaccuracy

Tags: css, mobile, android-browser

I try to create 3 divs that covers whole space on mobile browser.

I occurred little problem.

With this styles:

```
<style>
            body, html {
              width:100%;
              height:100%;
              padding: 0;
              margin: 0;

            }

            .game-button {
              width:100%;
              padding:0;
              margin: 0;
              height:40%;       // 2*40% = 80%;


            }

            #first-player {
              background-color: #ff0000;
            }

            #second-player {
              background-color: #00ff00;
            }


            #lights {
              padding: 0;
              margin: 0;
              height:20%;
            }
</style>
```

And this html code:

```
<body>
      <div id="first-player" class="game-button"></div>
      <div id="lights"></div>
      <div id="second-player" class="game-button"></div>
</body>
```

The problem is the "white bar on the bottom of the screen"  despite covering 100% of height in CSS.

Screenshot: ( it could be seen only on dark background so I link to imgur):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIXsi.jpg

This effect sometimes (on one on my phones) doesn't exists when I delete :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />
```

Here is the page

http://twigit.pl/game.html

```
with <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no"/>
```

http://twigit.pl/game2.html

```
withOUT <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some mobile browsers will auto-scale unless you tell them otherwise. What's the problem?

EDIT: you should also set the viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and check this out

http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile/

Comment: http://jsbin.com/exorat/13   <- Even this viewport leave the "white bar" on the bottom"  despite covering 100% of height by css

Comment: The problem is the "white bar on the bottom"